# Callback in Golang

Tags: callback, go, couchbase

I am using go-couchbase to update data to couchbase, however, I have problem in how to use the callback function.

The function `Update` requires me to pass a callback function in which should be `UpdateFunc`

```
func (b *Bucket) Update(k string, exp int, callback UpdateFunc) error
```

So that's what I have done

First, I declared a type `UpdateFunc`:

```
type UpdateFunc func(current []byte) (updated []byte, err error)
```

Then in the code, I add the following lines:

```
fn := UpdateFunc{func(0){}}
```

and then call the `Update` function:

```
bucket.Update("12345", 0, fn()}
```

But the Go returns the following error:

```
syntax error: unexpected literal 0, expecting ) for this line fn := UpdateFunc{func(0){}}
```

So what I am doing wrong? So how can I make the callback function work ?

## additional information

Thanks all of your suggestion. Now I can run the callback function as follows:

```
myfunc := func(current []byte)(updated []byte, err error) {return updated, err }

myb.Update("key123", 1, myfunc)
```

However, when I run the Update function of the bucket. I checked the couch database. The document with the key of "key123" was disappeared. It seems the Update does not update the value but delete it. What happened?

Comment: I think it may be giving you poorly-formatted error messages because it looks like your error is on the line `bucket.Update("12345",0,fn()}` (note the mismatched curly brace and parenthesis - it should be `bucket.Update("1234",0,fn())`).

Answer (score 11):

You need to create a function that matches the `couchbase.UpdateFunc` signature then pass it to `bucket.Update`.

For example:

```
fn := func(current []byte) (updated []byte, err error) {
    updated = make([]byte, len(current))
    copy(updated, current)
    //modify updated
    return
}

....

bucket.Update("12345",0,fn)
```

Notice that to pass a function you just pass `fn` not `fn()`, that would actually call the function right away and pass the return value of it.

I highly recommend stopping everything you're doing and reading [Effective Go](http://tip.golang.org/doc/effective_go.html) and all the posts on Go's [blog](http://blog.golang.org/) starting with [First Class Functions in Go](http://blog.golang.org/first-class-functions-in-go-and-new-go).

Answer (score 4):

Same answer I posted on the go-nuts list, just in case:

You don't have to define the UpdateFunc type by yourself, it's already defined here:

https://github.com/couchbaselabs/go-couchbase/blob/master/client.go#L608

just define the function normally and pass it as an argument or pass an anonymous function as in other languages.

here's a simple example:

http://play.golang.org/p/YOKxRtQqmU

Comment: Thanks all of your suggestion. Now I can run the callback function as follows:   
myfunc := func(current []byte)(updated []byte, err error) {return updated, err }      

myb.Update("key123", 1, myfunc)

However, when I run the Update function of the bucket. I checked the couch database. The document with the key of "key123" was disappeared. It seems the Update does not update the value but delete it. What happened?

Thanks